# Proving Perceptron algorithm mistake bound is tight

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, perceptron

How would I prove the Perception mistake bound is tight. Avrim Blum’s lecture notes claim that the upper bound for mistakes is $\frac{R}{\gamma}^2$, but I don’t understand how to prove this is mistake bound is tight

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: At least you should bother typing what $R$ and $\gamma$ are, or linking the lecture notes in the question.  As it is written, I believe very few people could understand what the question is about.